# Overwriting data in XLSX with python

Tags: python, excel, file, xlsx, xlsxwriter

Let's assume an excel file mismatch.xlsx at a particular location in C: drive

what I want to do is first check if it exists, and if it does I want to clear all the data in it and write new data into it

if it does not exist at all I would like to create a new file "mismatch.xlsx" at a particular location and write data into it

so far I am able to create a new file "mismatch.xlsx" and write into it but if I run the program again, I get permission denied error

this is my code to write data into "mismtach.xlsx"(i have used xlsxwriter), I am assuming the solution to this is a simple 'if' loop to check for file existence, but I am new to python and I am not sure how to declare that.

```
with xlsxwriter.Workbook('<location>/mismtach.xlsx') as workbook:
           worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
           worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet()
           worksheet3 = workbook.add_worksheet()
           
           for row_num , data in enumerate(mismatch_true):
                worksheet.write_row(row_num, 0, data)  
           for row_num2 , data2 in enumerate(semi):
                worksheet2.write_row(row_num2, 0, data2) 
           for row_num3 , data3 in enumerate(quarter):
               worksheet3.write_row(row_num3, 0, data3)
```

ERROR: xlsxwriter.exceptions.FileCreateError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
'(location)/mismtach.xlsx'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this meet what you are after?

```
import os
import xlsxwriter

# Excel File Name
xlfile = "mismtach.xlsx"

# Excel File Exits Then Remove
if os.path.exists(xlfile):
    os.remove(xlfile)

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(xlfile)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet3 = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
(your data)

# Close Workbook.
workbook.close(xlfile)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted.